# A set of bounded and continuous functions under supnorm is a commutative algebra with a multiplication identity

Tags: real-analysis, commutative-algebra, real-numbers

Question:

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Denote all bounded and continuous functions from $X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $BC(X,\mathbb{R})$, the topology of which is supnorm. Show that $BC(X,\mathbb{R})$ is a commutative algebra with a multiplication identity

Thoughts:

(1) I define some basic settings: $(f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ and $(fg)(x) = f(x)g(x)$. Also, for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, define $(\alpha f)(x) = \alpha f(x)$.

(2) Then I think I need to prove it in three steps, but I don't know how to do it, especially what I should do about $\circ$:

(i) $BC(X,\mathbb{R})$ is an algebra:

for every $a$, $b$, $c \in BC(X,\mathbb{R})$, they satisfy:

$a \circ (b \circ c) = (a \circ b) \circ c$

$a \circ (b+c) = (a \circ b) + (a \circ c)$

$(a+b) \circ c = (a \circ c) + (b \circ c)$

(ii) $BC(X,\mathbb{R})$ is a commutative algebra:

$a \circ b = b\circ a$ for all $a$, $b \in A$

(iii) $BC(X,\mathbb{R})$ has a multiplicative identity:

$a \circ 1 = 1 \circ a = a$ for all $a \in A$

I am having a hard time to transform $\circ$ to something related to the supnorm that I can compute. Can anyone give me some hints on it? I feel like I can solve the rest of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now what you've done so far is almost complete. You've not shown that $B(X,\Bbb R)$ is closed under the operations of point wise multiplication and addition. But that is easy:

If $f,g$ are bounded and continuous on $X$, then $\|f+g\| \leq \|f\| +\|g\|$(where $\| \|$ is the sup norm). I've used the famous triangle ineqaulity here. If you've not encountered this before, take it as an exercise(it follows from the triangle inequality for real numbers). This shows that $f+g$ is bounded. I'll leave it to you to show that $f+g$ is continuous. Hence $B(X,\Bbb R)$ is closed under point wise addition.

Similar arguments show that $B(X,\Bbb R)$ is closed under multiplication. With this and what you've done, what you sought out to prove is complete.

Comment: Actually, I have not proved the whole step 2. I think the basic question that I want to get clarification is that what is $\circ$?

Comment: it is pointwise multiplication

Comment: I have finished the proof I listed above. In fact, I even added the proof of a vector space at the very beginning. Can you explain why I need to additionally show that $BC(X, \mathbb{R})$ is closed under point-wise multiplication and addition? I didn't see where the proof is required to do so.

Comment: If you show it's closed under multiplication then you don't need to show it's a vector space over $\Bbb R$. This is because the scalars can be identified with the constant functions.

Comment: Oh, I see. So another way around, since I have showed that it is a vector space, then I don't need to show that it is closed?

Comment: No you still have to prove(if you haven't) that it is closed under pointwise multiplication. What you've done so far is that you've proved it's closed under scalar multiplication and addition(the argument I gave).

Comment: I got the point. It is very clear and seems very easy to finish. But still I am confused that why I need to show $BC(X,\mathbb{R})$ is closed under scalar multiplication, pointwise multiplication, and addition? Based on the logic I listed in the question, I have shown vector space $\rightarrow$ algebra $\rightarrow$ communicative algebra $\rightarrow$ multiplication identity. There is no step that requires a closed $BC(X,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Have you done group theory? For instance, is the set of positive reals closed under the operation $a \circ b= a-b$? It isn't. So it's important to check closure

Comment: How do you know that if $f,g \in B(X,\Bbb R)$, then $f+g \in B(X,\Bbb R)$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108538/discussion-between-noah-and-pankaj-tiwari).